# Await promises affecting code sequence. Javascript Script using Puppeteer and MSAL login

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, azure-ad-msal

I am writing a script using "Puppeteer" and when using headless = false, the script stops after I enter my password in MSAL, it stalls and doesn't finish the rest of the script. It stalls on line 37 (I highlighted the code line in caps as a comment)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

msal = async () => {
    // Set up page
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://testurl.com');

// Login from Landing Page
await page.waitForSelector('#login-btn', {
    visible: true
});
const loginButton = await page.$('#login-btn');
await Promise.all([
    await loginButton.click(),
    page.waitForNavigation(),
]);

// Login MSAL info
await page.waitForSelector('#i0116', {
    visible: true
});
// Email
const emailInput = await page.$('#i0116');
await emailInput.type('testuser@hello.com');
const submitButton = await page.$('#idSIButton9');
await submitButton.click();
// Password
await page.waitForSelector('#i0118', {
    visible: true
});
passwordInput = await page.$('#i0118');

await passwordInput.type('password123');

// HERE IS WHERE IT STALLS

const submitButton2 = await page.$('#idSIButton9');
await submitButton2.click()
const submitButton3 = await page.$('#idSIButton9');
await submitButton3.click()
// page.waitForNavigation();
// console.log(page.url());

await page.waitForSelector('#welcome-banner-title-h2', {
    visible: true
});

// Validate login via url via redirect        
if (page.url() != 'https://testurl.com') {
    console.error('login failed!');
} else {
    console.log('login succeeded');
}
await page.close();
}
msal();
```

**UPDATE**

1. The cursor just blinks on the password input field.
2. There is no activity in the console or network tab in inspector.
3. The id i0118 is the correct id assigned for that DOM object.

Comment: can you explain what "Stalls" means? Do you see a network transfer in the puppetter dev tools (since you're not running headless)? Any throws on the console? Also, how did you determine that's where it stalls, rather than on any of the subsequent lines? And then finally, _does that element exist at all_ (as in, the one your code claims exists, not whether there's "a password field". Is there an actual element with id `i0118` or are you making puppeteer wait for 30 seconds because it will run `.type()` once the element becomes available?

Comment: 1. The cursor just blinks on the password input field. 2. There is no activity in the console or network tab in inspector.  3. The id i0118 is the correct id assigned for that DOM object.  Thanks for the help in advance!!

Comment: Thanks, but please remember to put that in your post rather than a comment (requests for more information are always to make sure your post [has all the details](/help/how-how-to-ask), so please make sure to still your post. As for 3: do note that that `passwordInput` missing a leading `const`. Same for `msal `, so at the very least you probably want to run this through a linter to make sure all the "might not be related but is technically questionable code" bits get fixes so you can rules those out.